# User Signup in Multisite - Need Plugin or Advice

Tags: plugins, multisite

I'm trying to make some modifications to a wordpress multisite and i could use some help from someone more experienced.
I want to restrict the acces to my blogs unless the user has an account.
In detail : i have a series of blogs, each one with an admin/autor. If a user wants to read posts from a blog, he should first go on the main site, to wp-signup.php and create an account.
I'm planning on creating a plugin, active on all subsites.
Is this possible? if yes, could someone give me some directions - wich hooks, filters and functions i would need ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Test](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) if the current visitor is logged in and registered as user

```
// If the user's not registered & logged in, abort
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
    return;
```

[Test](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can_for_blog) if the currently logged in user has a capability for the specific blog

```
$blog_id = ''; // You need to retrieve and set that here
// If the currently logged in user hasn't got the 'manage_options' cap - which is assigned to admins and above - abort
if ( ! current_user_can_for_blog( $blog_id, 'manage_options' ) )
    return;
```

If it's not necessary to check for a specific blog, we can test just the capability.

```
// If the currently logged in user hasn't got the 'manage_options' cap - which is assigned to admins and above - abort
if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )
    return;
```

[This](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/your-friendly-current-user-deamon/) (old and not maintained) plugin gives you better in-depth look at what users deliver.